# using stream instead of for loop for maps in java

Tags: java, lambda, stream, java-stream, collectors

I am working on java project where I have to iterate a list and put values in a new map based on computations in that list.

Here's whats working using a basic for loop:

```
    Map<Long, PickingDetails> pickingDetailsDTOMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<pickingJobModels.size();i++)
     {
 pickingDetailsDTOMap.put(pickingJobModels.get(i).getPickListDTO().getReferenceId(),getPickingDetails(pickingJobModels.get(i)));
      }
```

But I want to do it with streams so I did this:

```
pickingJobModels.stream().map(pickingJobModel -> pickingDetailsDTOMap.put(pickingJobModel.getPickListDTO().getReferenceId(),getPickingDetails(pickingJobModel)));
```

but when I return that `pickingDetailsDTOMap` I get empty map.

Any suggestions how to use stream in this case?

Comment: have you tried adding a collector at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the correct way. `map` is an intermediate operation (i.e. it is evaluated lazily) and you have no terminal operation, so it's never evaluated. You should `collect` the data into a `Map`:

```
Map<Long, PickingDetails> pickingDetailsDTOMap = 
    pickingJobModels.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(pm -> pm.getPickListDTO().getReferenceId(),
                                              pm -> getPickingDetails(pm)));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a stream, you create a definition of operations. These operations are to be executed one after the other for each element traveling through the stream.

It is like setting up people and giving them instructions. The first one, the stream's source has the instruction: if the next person standing to the right of you is asking for a value from you, give them the next element from this array, collection, or whatever the stream source is.

The following person is doing the "map" gets the instruction: whenever someone standing to the right of you asks a value from you, then you first request a value from the man standing on your left, do the map operation on the value and give the person to the right.

The last man in the row, the terminal operation is the ONLY ONE getting an instruction that says: actively ask for values from the person on your left and collect these values.

What you did giving two men the instructions, but there is no terminal operation executing the stream.

Streams are executed from right to left. If there is no terminal operation, then nothing will happen.